# Does anyone know where I can get a linux python SDK for azure?

Tags: python, linux, azure

I've been looking high and low. The microsoft website even has this link - https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/common-tasks/install-python/ but when I follow the instruction to execute the curl command and I type in my password it blows up with 'an error occured...' message.

I also found this - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/ - but when I click on the download link I always get a 400KB file (which feels small for an SDK) and if I try to untar it I get a bunch of errors.

Can anyone point me to a reliable mechanism for getting the SDK? I've gotta believe it's out there somewhere.

Comment: ok, I feel a little silly, but so should the person who built the tarball!  I just assumed the tarball was corrupted because of all those messages but it in fact did untar.  BUT all the files were installed in non-standard tarball directories so I ever saw them.  So now I'm trying the instruction in the INSTALL file and it wants me to install npn and Node.js.  Why do I need something in js when I'm trying to do python.  This is soooo non-typical.  In fact, I can't even figure out how to install Node.js as there's no such debuan package with that name.

Answer (score 0):

From [python SDK Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/). In [install python and the SDK](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/common-tasks/install-python/) you can see how can be installed.

Comment: my question is where do I get the SDK, I'm looking for a specific URL because when I tried both the ones listed in my basenote, which are also the one I ultimately browse to in your link above I can't get it to work.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but am clueless as to what it might be.

Comment: that points me to the same tarball I mentioned above.  I download it just fine but when I run 'tar -zxf against it I get errors'.    <pre><code>mjs@blkjak:~/Downloads$ tar -zxf azure-2012-12.tar.gz  2>&1| more
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.ino'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.nlink'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword `SCHILY.dev'   </pre></code>

Comment: Can someone also tell me how to format a comment with a 'code' block?  According to the 'learn more' below is says to preface your block with 4 spaces which I did but it didn't do what I wanted and when that didn't work I tried inserting the <pre><code> block myself.  sorry about the mess